# javascript crashing when running quicksort

Tags: javascript, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to write a quicksort in javascript and display the sorted output. But Whenever I run the execute() function the program hangs and stopped responding. Why is this? I'm not so familiar with javascript and I just translated this from my java code. But I just don't see why it didn't work. Here the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function exchange(a, i, j) {
   var k = a[i];
   a[i] = a[j];
   a[j] = k;
}
function partition(a2, lo, hi) {
   var i2 = lo;
   var j2 = hi + 1;
   var v = a2[lo];
   while (true) {
       while (a2[++i2] < v) {
          if (i2 == hi) {
              break;
          }
       }
       while (v < a2[--j2]) {
         if (j2 == lo) {
            break;
         }
       }
       if (i2 >= j2) {
          break;
       }
       exchange(a2, i2, j2);
   }
   exchange(a2, lo, j2);
   return j2;
}
function sort(a3, lo2, hi2) {
   var j3 = partition(a3, lo2, hi2);
   sort(a3, lo2, j3 - 1);
   sort(a3, j 3+ 1, hi2);
}
function sort(a4) {
   sort(a4, 0, a.length - 1);
}
function execute() {
   var array = document.getElementById("texts").value.split(' ');
   sort(array);
   for (a in array) {
       document.write(array[a] + "<br>");
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you debugged through this to see where it is hanging?

Comment: This looks funny: `sort(a3, j 3+ 1, hi2);`. That should be `j3`, right?

Comment: Guessing you are either blowing the stack because of a recursive call that goes too deep, or the browser is becoming unresponsive because a section of code is taking too long to execute. Also, you have 2 definitions of `sort()`. JavaScript doesn't support overloaded methods in the usual OOP way. That's probably part of the issue. I'm guessing you're calling the second definition of `sort()`. That's why you didn't catch what @Guffa is pointing out in his comment. Because that code isn't executed.

Comment: @pge, I didn't know about java script not doing the same as OOP does. I just translated this from java I didn't rewrite it. Can you explain further regarding the overloaded methods? And about the second definition of sort you mean the recurssive sort with 3 parameters or the sort with 1? Which is not exxecuting?

Comment: @pje, I didn't know about java script not doing the same as OOP does. I just translated this from java I didn't rewrite it. Can you explain further regarding the overloaded methods? And about the second definition of sort you mean the recurssive sort with 3 parameters or the sort with 1? Which is not exxecuting? –

Comment: @recursivePointer JavaScript is not like Java, despite the similarities of their names. Honestly, rather than explaining different aspects of the language to you, it makes more sense to just tell you to find a good JavaScript book and start from their. Two of the best books for understanding the nature of JavaScript are Douglas Crockford's canonical *JavaScript: The Good Parts* and John Resig and Bear Bibeault's *Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja*. Just search them on Amazon. These two books will give you an understanding of JavaScript that few have. And they are pretty fun reads too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are implementing quick-sort just for fun, consider using the `sort()` method on the Array object:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.sort(); // result: Apple,Banana,Mango,Orange
```

When sorting numbers, pass a function to `sort()` to determine whether to sort in ascending or descending order:

```
var numbers = [2,41,5,2,16,7];
numbers.sort(function (a,b) { return a-b; });
// result: 2,2,5,7,16,41
```

If you want to implement quick sort in JavaScript just for fun, consider reading through: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/11/27/computer-science-in-javascript-quicksort/. It gives a nice walkthrough of the algorithm, and some example code.

Reference: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Quicksort</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quicksort.js" >
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="qsform" action="" method="" >
<input type="text" size="80" name="unsorted" value="S C K U P E M I B R" /> <br />
<input type="button" name="sort" value="Sort" onclick="dosort(this.form)" /> <br />
<input type="text" size="80" name="sorted" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the javacsript code for this form is given below

```
   Array.prototype.swap=function(i, j)
   {
   var tmp=this[i];
   this[i]=this[j];
   this[j]=tmp;
   }

   function partition(array, a2, lo, hi)
   {
   var piv=array[hi];
   array.swap(hi, lo-1);
   var store=a2;
   var ix;
   for(ix=a2; ix<lo-1; ++ix) {
   if(array[ix]<=piv) {
   array.swap(store, ix);
   ++store;
   }
   }
   array.swap(lo-1, store);

   return store;
   }

   function qsort(array, a2, lo)
   {
   if(lo-1>a2) {
   var hi=a2+Math.floor(Math.random()*(lo-a2));

   hi=partition(array, a2, lo, hi);

   qsort(array, a2, hi);
   qsort(array, hi+1, lo);
   }
   }

   function quick_sort(array)
   {
   qsort(array, 0, array.length);
   }

   function dosort(form)
   {
   var array=form.unsorted.value.split(/ +/);

   quick_sort(array);

   form.sorted.value=array.join(' ');
   }
```